# Edit Enterprise Resource using CSOM - Project Server 2013

Tags: client-object-model, project-server

I'm trying to add a new calendar exception to a specific resource using CSOM.
However, when trying to update the resource, I'm getting a `PJClientCallableException: CalendarExceptionConflict`, which according to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms508961.aspx), seems to occur when there's a conflict in the calendar exceptions.

Here's a piece of my code:

```
        var creationInfo = new CalendarExceptionCreationInformation();
        creationInfo.Name = "Vacaciones CSOM";

        // Specify (¿optional?) properties.
        creationInfo.Start = DateTime.Today;
        creationInfo.Finish = DateTime.Today.AddDays(5);

        var resourceId = "XXX";
        var resource = projContext.EnterpriseResources.GetById(resourceId);

        projContext.Load(resource);
        projContext.Load(resource.ResourceCalendarExceptions);
        projContext.ExecuteQuery(); 

        // Add the calendar exception to the collection.
        resource.ResourceCalendarExceptions.Add(creationInfo); 

        // Submit the request to update the collection on the server
        projContext.EnterpriseResources.Update();
        projContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

Any advise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it!
The problem was there was another Calendar Exception in the period I was trying to create.
Hope it helps!